# Why Couldn't I set the OneToOneField in ModelForm's save() function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Let's say we got two model:

## model.py

```
class Engine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    engine = models.OneToOneField(Engine)
```

## engine_admin.py

```
class EngineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
         return EngineChangeListForm
```

## form.py

```
class EngineChangeListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Engine
        fields = []
    # this work!
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        car_obj = Car.objects.create(engine = self.instance)
        return super(EngineChangeListForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if I change save() to below, it would create a new car object, but in the end, engine object's car field will be empty.

I don't understand why the code below won't work.

```
# this won't work!
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     car_obj = Car.objects.create(engine = self.instance)
     self.instance.car = car_obj
     return super(EngineChangeListForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. The `get_changelist_form` is undocumented, are you sure you want to use it? Calling `Car.objects.create` in the `save()` method means you'll create a new car *every* time you save the engine. Why do you want to do that? You'll end up with lots of cars without any engines.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `super()` first to save the engine, before you create the car.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(EngineChangeListForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    car_obj = Car.objects.create(engine=instance)
    return instance
```

Comment: when to call super() doesn't matter in my case.

Comment: Until you call `super()`, the instance does not have a primary key. I believe that assigning that instance to a car or setting `instance.car` will set `car.engine_id` to `None`. Django doesn't go back and set the foreign key correctly when the instance is finally saved, so you end up with an engine without a car.